# Why do i get ValueError trying to make a box plot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to make box plot, so for this reason I create list of dataframes connected to labels of boxplot and still got ValueError:

```
ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 20 to array axis with dimension 2
```

but they are connected i really can't understand
My code:

```
    uniq = pd.unique(data[columns[0]]).tolist()
    data_to = []
    for item in uniq:
        data_to.append(data[columns[1] and data[columns[0]] == item])
    fig, ax = ppl.subplots()
    ax.boxplot(data_to, labels=uniq)
    ax.set_ylabel(columns[1])
    ax.set_xlabel(columns[0])
    ax.set_title = 'Диаграмма "Бокса-Вискера" для столбца '+columns[0]
    ppl.show()
```

I'm trying to make box plot, so for this reason I create list of dataframes connected to labels of boxplot and still got ValueError:

```
ValueError: Dimensions of labels and X must be compatible
```

but they are connected i really can't understand
My code:

```
    uniq = pd.unique(data[columns[0]]).tolist()
    data_to = []
    for item in uniq:
        data_to.append(data[columns[1] and data[columns[0]] == item])
    fig, ax = ppl.subplots()
    ax.boxplot(data, labels=uniq)
    ax.set_ylabel(columns[1])
    ax.set_xlabel(columns[0])
    ax.set_title = 'Диаграмма "Бокса-Вискера" для столбца '+columns[0]
    ppl.show()
```

that's the data (not full due to website)

```
   Пол  Возраст
0    Ж       18
1    Ж       17
2    Ж       15
3    Ж       15
4    Ж       16
5    M       16
6    M       16
7    Ж       17
```

and columns:

```
['Пол', 'Возраст']
```

Thanks

Comment: The data is not compatible with the labels. Could you post the value of `data` and `columns` to your question?

Comment: sure I've added

Comment: Try running `ax.boxplot(data[columns[1]])` instead of `ax.boxplot(data, labels=uniq)`. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I would like to show boxes for each unique value in `column[0]` and I form `data_to` for it

Comment: And then i get another `ValueError` :  `ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 20 to array axis with dimension 2`

Answer (score 0):

`for` loop isn't the best way to get unique values. Here's a simpler way to get what you want:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as ppl


data = pd.DataFrame({"Пол": ['Ж', 'Ж', 'Ж', 'Ж', 'Ж', 'M', 'M', 'Ж'],
                    "Возраст": [18, 17, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 17]})
columns = ['Пол', 'Возраст']


fig, ax = ppl.subplots()
data.boxplot(column=columns[1], by=columns[0], ax=ax)
ax.set_ylabel(columns[1])
ax.set_xlabel(columns[0])
ax.set_title = 'Диаграмма "Бокса-Вискера" для столбца '+columns[0]
ppl.show()
```

Which results in this graph:

[image]